# create a view of 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with some columns and another table that I want its rows as columns to the view.

```
table1
uid|atr1|atr2|atr3

table2
uid|col1|col2

profile_fields(this is a dynamic table, thats why its rows)
fid|name

profile_values
fid|uid|value
```

so In the end I want a view like that and 1 row for each uid:

```
View
uid|atr1|atr2|atr3|col1|col2|name(all row names here from profile_Fields)|
```

and 1 entry row for each uid with all its user data and values

I dont understand how to make the view with the profile_fields because it has rows and not columns. It worked without this table in the first place but can't make it work like I explained above.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the `profile_fields`? Provide table structure and data example.

Comment: I think this is not supported as you can read here: select_statement can select from base tables or other views (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html).

Comment: profile_fields(columns fid|name)
and has some rows for example 1|category1, 2|category2, 3|category3 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a pivot table mechanism, e.g. -

```
SELECT pv.*,
  MAX(IF(pf.field = 'Category1', pv.value, NULL)) AS Category1,
  MAX(IF(pf.field = 'Category2', pv.value, NULL)) AS Category2,
  MAX(IF(pf.field = 'Category3', pv.value, NULL)) AS Category3
FROM profile_values pv
  LEFT JOIN profile_fields pf
    ON pv.fid = pf.fid
GROUP BY uid
```

Then join this query to your tables.